# Starting different activities from MainActivity on button click

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop android apps with C# and xamarin.

I have two buttons on my MainActivity. On each button click I want to open different activities, i.e., activity1 and activity2.

Below is my code for the MyActivity.

By using this code activity2 is opening on button2 click. But when I press button1 it gives an error.

Please suggest me a C# code to open multiple activities from main activity

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Title = null;

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(activity1));

            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        button2.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(activity2));
            StartActivity(intent2);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: What is the trigger point where you want to open multiple activities ?

Comment: Can you help us out with what error do you get that would help actually

Comment: Java ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

If you had tried everything, I wrote a demo about your needs.

First of all, run my demo in your VS, if you can running it and get a correct result, please compare these projects line by line.

If not, this issue was related to the VS or build environment.
https://github.com/851265601/TestActivity

Comment: @user4584148 Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can open new activity (if you do not need to pass any additional information) via `StartActivity(typeof(targetActivity))`

Comment: same problem after doing this also

Comment: Java ClassNotFoundException